# Is it safe to append a variable in array of structure during upgrade the contract?

Tags: solidity, storage, openzeppelin

I'm working on an upgradable contract using Openzeppelin upgrade.

I'm aware that upgrading the contract must take the storage layout into consideration.

However, I'm still not so confident about the safeness when I want to upgrade the `mapping of struct` OR `array of the struct`.

For example, Is it safe to change from

```
struct User {
   bytes32 name;
}

contract Sample {
   mapping(uint32 => User) userById;
   User[] users;
}
```

To this

```
struct User {
   bytes32 name;
   uint256 age;
   uint256[] friends;
}

contract Sample {
   mapping(uint32 => User) userById;
   User[] users;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is not safe because of the `User` array isn't compatible with the previous storage layout.

```
User[] users;
```

Solidity stores array continuously `User[0] | User[1] | ...` with each user using the same amount of storage slots.

The old `User` occupies a single storage slot while the new uses three. So items the new version will be overlapping.

Comment: So if a new member is appended to the `Checkpoint` struct used in [`ERC20VotesUpgradeable` here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/fd165faaf00587377b5ab93be3cafb4ffdc96976/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20VotesUpgradeable.sol#L41), it will break compatibility, right?

Comment: @Pang Yes, a Checkpoint is 1 slot (=32 bytes), so any new member will make it at least 2 slots, and layout incompatibel.